# Why does this function display twice ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My input is

```
{
    "location": {
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "addres1",
        "phone": "637636***",
        "facility": "facility1",
        "lat": //this is lattitude, 
        "lng": //this is longitude
    }, 
    "distance": 859.2556649163248
}
```

This is how it is being processed:

```
    function Turup() {
     return Object.entries(nearbyPlace).map(([key, value], i) => {
          return (
               <div>
                    <ul key={key}>
                         <li className='font-bold'>name :</li>
                         <li>address : </li>
                         <li>phone : </li>
                         <li>facility : </li>
                         <li>latitude : </li>
                         <li>longitude : </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
          )
     })
}
```

this functional component return twice result, but one has a value and the other has an empty value

Comment: They are called [Function Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components). They are (generally) not [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming).

Comment: "this functional component return twice result" — How are you determining this?

Comment: What is stored in nearbyPlace?

Comment: You have two `return` statements, shouldn't one be `render()`

Comment: Charchit Kapoor, const nearbyPlace = findNearestLocation(myLocation, locations);

Comment: @geertjanknapen — No. One is `Turup`'s, one is the arrow function that is passed to `map` and this is a function component not a class component so there is no `render` method.

Comment: @Quentin I got this code on stackoverflow. but the result comes out twice

Comment: The result comes out twice … where?

Comment: @Quentin in my browser

Comment: And that looks like what? Do you have two lists? Why do you expect only one list? You never really answered Charchit. What is stored in nearbyPlace?

Comment: How many times your `.map` function is called depends on `nearbyPlace` object, so. I would suggest to console log `nearbyPlace` object and share those logs.

Comment: This code will create a <ul> without any dynamic content for each element of `nearbyPlaces`. Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: @BipinMaharjan {
    "location": {
        "name": "name1",
        "address": "addres1",
        "phone": "637636***",
        "facility": "facility1",
        "lat": //this is lattitude,
        "lng": //this is longitude
    },
    "distance": 859.2556649163248
}

Comment: @FaliqulIsbah — That object has two entries in it (location and distance). Why would you expect only one list when you have two entries? (For that matter, since the values of location and distance are so different, why would you use object.entries with a map anyway?)

Comment: @Quentin I'm just learning reactjs. and i got the problem but when i search on stackoverflow i found the almost matching problem. and when I practice it comes out twice. but what i want it to show once which only show location object

Comment: `Object.entries` and `map` have nothing to do with React. They are core JS. You need to figure out what you actually want to show and think about how to get that from the data structure you have. Since you have only one thing, it doesn't make sense to use `Object.entries` or `map`

Comment: thanks @Quentin ,for responding to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have an object and you try to loop it as if it was an array. Since the object has two members, namely `location` and `distance` on the first level, you get two iterations. Proof-of-concept:

```js
var nearbyPlace = [{
    location: {
        name: "name1",
        address: "addres1",
        phone: "637636***",
        facility: "facility1",
        lat: 123, 
        lng: 456
    }, 
    distance: 859.2556649163248
}]

    function Turup() {
     return Object.entries(nearbyPlace).map(([key, value], i) => {
          return (
               `<div>
                    <ul key=${key}>
                         <li className='font-bold'>name :</li>
                         <li>address : ${value.location.address}</li>
                         <li>phone : ${value.location.phone}</li>
                         <li>facility : ${value.location.facility}</li>
                         <li>latitude : ${value.location.lat}</li>
                         <li>longitude : ${value.location.lng}</li>
                    </ul>
               </div>`
          )
     })
}

let turup = Turup();
console.log({length: turup.length, content:turup});
```

Quick solution

```
    function Turup() {
     return Object.entries([nearbyPlace]).map(([key, value], i) => {
          return (
               <div>
                    <ul key={key}>
                         <li className='font-bold'>name :</li>
                         <li>address : </li>
                         <li>phone : </li>
                         <li>facility : </li>
                         <li>latitude : </li>
                         <li>longitude : </li>
                    </ul>
               </div>
          )
     })
    }
```

Notice the `[` and `]` around `nearbyPlace`, those are converting your input into a 1-element array. If you will always have a single element, then doing a loop on `entries` is unnecessary and superfluous, but it is you who has to determine whether you need a loop.

Comment: it works fine, but the values of name, address, phone etc are not showing

Comment: @FaliqulIsbah you will need to look into key and value and change the template accordingly. My answer focused on how you can make your code work with the proper number of iterations, you should `console.log(value)` in the inner function in order to find out what members it has. And then use this knowledge to adjust your template.

Comment: my input is the result of console.log

Comment: @FaliqulIsbah edited my snippet accordingly.